# npm not installing in the correct directory

Tags: node.js, npm

```js
C:\Users\User>cd onedrive/desktop/folder

C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\folder>npm i node-superfetch

up to date, audited 23 packages in 1s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\folder>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8E2E-B533

 Directory of C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\folder

15/11/2021  10:49 AM    <DIR>          .
15/11/2021  11:03 AM    <DIR>          ..
15/11/2021  10:45 AM                 0 data.json
15/11/2021  10:50 AM                92 index.js
               2 File(s)             92 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  395,067,858,944 bytes free
```

I wanted to install a npm package in the `folder` directory and it does install it but I have no idea where it installed it to. I just reinstalled nodejs and the issue isn't gone. I typed `npm config get prefix` and this is what it shows:

```js
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\folder>npm config get prefix
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: npm installs packages into the node_modules directory

Comment: @about14sheep yes i know that, my problem is that the node_modules folder isn't being created in the current directory

Comment: did you run npm init before installing?

Answer (score 0):

To see where `npm` will install, run [`npm root`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-root).

One possibility is that you have `global` set to `true` in a relevant `.npmrc` file. If so, `npm root` will report the global installation directory rather than the local `node_modules`. If you can't find where `global` is being set to `true`, you can use `--no-global` on the command with `npm install` so that it ignores the setting and installs things in the local `node_modules` instead. You can also set it to false in the project `.npmrc` which will override it being set in `.npmrc` files elsewhere.